# Hide specific groups on PeoplePicker in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, people-picker

In our AD, even the mail-distribution-groups are flagged as "Security Groups", which allows the PeoplePicker in SharePoint to use the groups to set permissions on sites, lists and such.

Is there a chance to configure the PeoplePicker in a way that it will not offer groups with a specific display-name or attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom active directory query. This is done at the web application level. Here is an example using PowerShell:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication http://yourwebapp.com
$webapp.PeoplePickerSettings #Displays your current values

#Finds users with an email address, who are not disabled, and account name 
#not ending in VDI or group name not ending in -Test
$webapp.PeoplePickerSettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = "(|(&((objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!sAMAccountName=*-VDI)))(&((objectCategory=Group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4)(!cn=*-Test))))"

$webapp.Update() #commits the change
$webapp.PeoplePickerSettings #Displays the updated values
```

This query will trim users with account names ending in -VDI and groups with names ending in -Test. Here is a breakdown of the query with comments (making it more of a psuedo query, since LDAP queries can't actually have comments):

```
(|  // or a person or group
    (&  // a person must match all of these conditions
        (
            (objectCategory=Person) 
            (objectClass=User)
            (mail=*)    // mail is not empty
            (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)  // account not disabled
            (!sAMAccountName=*-VDI)  // account name doesn't end with -VDI
        )
    )
    (&   // a group must match all of these
        (
            (objectCategory=Group) 
            (groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4)  // domain local group
            (!cn=*-Test)  // name doesn't end with -Test
        )
    )
)
```

Note: I don't have an easy way to test this at the moment, so my syntax may not be perfect but hopefully you get the idea. You'll need to adjust this to your needs, for instance you may not want only domain local groups.

Ref: [Another People Picker Post – SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2017/09/07/another-people-picker-post-sharepoint-2016/)

Should work the same for 2013.

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you!